# Debugging Object Snapshot

Tags: visual-studio-2008, debugging

I am wondering if it is possible to 'snapshot' an object when debugging in VS2008, basically I am working with a WCF Service and want to be able to debug my object and spend as long as I want looking at its properties before IIS kills my process.

Is it possible to move the complete object into isolation so that I can continue to look at it?

The object is not very big, I only care about its properties, no other calls need to be invoked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only need to inspect the object and not single step through the application, you could create a memory dump and debug that. Take a look at [Debugging Tools for Windows](http://www.microsoft.com/whdc/devtools/debugging/).

Comment: Thank you, I will check out the Debugging Tools